# Are front and back-end SSL certificates the same?

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up and API on https and I get the following error :

> NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I have generated the certificate using a IP address because I dont have any domain name for the server.

Answer (score 4):

The "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" SSL error indicates a certificate that is not signed by a verified certificate authority. This typically indicates a self-signed certificate, especially when you're dealing with server applications that you have not manually imported an SSL certificate signed by one of the verified certificate authorities into the application and it must generate its own to use for SSL functionality.

If it were an issue with an SSL certificate being signed for a certain name and the server being accessed through a different name, you would get the ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error, indicating that the name in the certificate doesn't match up with the name being used to access it. In your case, however, that doesn't apply.

There isn't an issue with an ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error, however. It has nothing to do with the fact that the certificate was generated with an IP address, it matters who generated it and the fact that that CA is most likely not in the database of verified authorities. It shouldn't pose a huge security issue for things that are not designed to directly interact with users (read: end-user services and websites). But if it is, you may want to invest in getting an SSL certificate signed by a valid certificate authority.